# problems installing homebrew on mavericks

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I tried to install homebrew (OSX 10.9.5) using the recommended

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

but got

```
Illegal variable name.
```

I do have macports installed, so perhaps some commands do not what they are meant to?? But note that ruby is /usr/bin/ruby and curl is /usr/bin/curl.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with usage of `tcsh` as underlying shell. `tcsh` does not support `$()` as a syntax for command substituion. When using `bash` instead, it works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

in terminal preferences, change /bin/tcsh to /bin/bash

Comment: Presumably the OP is using `tcsh` because they want to use it in preference to `bash`! They don't need to (semi)permanently change their shell - just drop into `bash` to install `brew`, then exit `bash` and return to `tcsh`. And that'll work even if they're using iTerm2, or another terminal emulator, not just Terminal.app.

Answer (score -2):

in terminal just type 
'bash' and then enter
now run the same command. I works fine.